# System ODBC not visible to user

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, odbc

We have made a couple of ODBC connections on the System DSN with the admin account. They are not visible to the users. This in Windows 7 with 64 bit OS. What do I need to do to get them visible. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From my personal experience, sometime you have a 32 bit app and this one is relying on the 32 bit driver, and when you configure a 64 bit, this is not accessible to the app, you can check that, running the version of `odbcad32` that appears under `windows\syswow64` to check if this one shows the same that is appearing with the version from `windows\system32`. HTH

Comment: Are you saying the application is one the other architect than the `DNS`? When I go to Admin Tools to open the ODBCs I don't see 32 vs 64 on this computer - though they both do exist. On my personal computer I see both and know to configure one for each architect.

Comment: In the properties I see the ODBC datasources is 32 bit, the app is likely 64. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: You have both administrators, one is for 32 bit and another one for 64 bit, one is located in \windows\system32 and the other in \windows\syswow64, you must configure in the one that is not configured your DSN, and also you must have the drivers for that platform, usually those are installed along, but, sometimes you have to run the installation again in order to be able to have both of them, I hope that this is clear enough to help you. PS, in both cases the name of the odbc admin is odbcad32.exe, you can run them from your explorer, I suggest you to run as Admin. HTH

Comment: I will see what I can do. This is a new area for me and I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: Yes, I can see both `odbcad32.exe`s in their respective folders.